# I am getting assembly reference missing error though added Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll to visual project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have added Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll as reference to the C# Visual Project. When tried retrieving methods of the added dll, I am getting Error "The type or namespace name 'globalpropertyschemas' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.BizTalk' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ".

Could you please help me if I am missing something?

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
hani9870

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to Vladimir Kirnishni for finding a fix. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkesb/thread/8c45dad8-4347-4046-baf6-c850ea89d9c3

Since this will not be the last time I install the portal, I am duplicating the list of steps here for quick access just in case the thread on the forum disappears.

```
1.  Unzip C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit\ESBSource.zip file into the C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB folder
2.  Remove Read-only attribute from all files in C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB folder.
3.  Download and install Enterprise Library 5.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104
4.  Download and install Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=577
5.  In Visual Studio 2012, open ESB.Portal.sln found in C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\ESB.Portal
6.  When Visual Studio 2012 starts converting the solution to the current format, a dialog pops up that warns you about ESB.Portal.Setup.vdproj file not being supported in Visual Studio 2012. Click OK. Wait until the solution opens.
7.  In the Solution Explorer add Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll as a reference to the ESB.BAM.Service.Implementation project. This assembly is found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0\Bin
8.  Open web.config file found in ESB.Portal project and remove (or comment out) “scripting” sectionGroup declaration that starts at line 12 and ends at line 20.
9.  Save all files in the solution.
10. Rebuild ESB.Portal solution.
11. Close Visual Studio.
12. Run Management_Install.cmd file found in C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\Install\Scripts
```